# Eclipse and unchecked conversion warnings that should not be there

Tags: java, eclipse

The code that gets the warning:

```
HashSet<MyBean> beanies = StatusUtil.getStatus(myBeanList);
```

The method that it calls:

```
public static HashSet<MyBean> getStatus(List<MyBean> servers){      
   HashSet<MyBean> set = new HashSet<MyBean>();
   return set;
}
```

Yes, this is the exact code in Eclipse. I realize that this isn't a ton of information, but it seems to me that code should not produce warnings. It is Eclipse Indigo if that helps. Cleaning the project does nothing. Restarting Eclipse does nothing.

**edit:** I should have noted originally that Eclipse actually says "the expression of type `HashSet` needs unchecked conversion to conform to `HashSet<MyBean>` ". So it seems to realize that the method is defined as HashSet but NOT realize that so is my return variable...

Comment: What is the defined type of `myBeanList`?

Comment: Your code seems to work without warnings http://ideone.com/2LVUOD. We need more informations to solve your problem.

Comment: @Pshemo you're probably assuming that `myBeanList` is a `List<MyBean>`. I think NilsH has hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @bmorris591 yes, my example shows that for `List<MyBean>` it works without warnings so it is very probable that type of `beanies` is the source of warning, like NilsH noticed.

Comment: @NilsH It's an ArrayList<MyBean> ..

Comment: @Pshemo But the warning in Eclipse says "The expression of type HashSet needs unchecked conversion to conform to HashSet<MyBean>". In other words Eclipse is too dumb to figure out the correct return type of the variable?? All the files are saved btw...

Comment: If Eclipse gives that warning, it should also say exactly which line gives the warning. What's the code on that line? Your sample code looks fine, so the error has to be somewhere else.

Comment: @KyleM but even when I change it to `ArrayList<MyBean>` the warning is not showing. Could you [[edit]] your question and provide some minimal but complete code example that will reproduce this behavior?

Comment: @NilsH Nope, that is the line it gives it on. Additionally, that is my exact code. It highlights the line in yellow, it would be impossible to miss. Obviously something is wrong with Eclipse, but I don't know what. This is the second time this has happened

Comment: @Pshemo No I can't, because apparently I am the only one who gets this behavior. That IS the complete code example. I think something is wrong with Eclipse. My coworker has looked also, and cannot say why I get the error.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding?

Comment: @acdcjunior Yup. It doesn't change the error.

Comment: Are you sure you have rebuilt the exact `StatusUtil` class that line is supposed to be using? Seems like it is using a different version of that class. Are they on the same project (the client class and `StatusUtil`)?

Comment: @KyleM do you also get warning for this code http://ideone.com/2LVUOD? If not then could you show what is after `ArrayList<MyBean> myBeanList = ...` in your code?

Comment: @acdcjunior Yeah I deleted the build directory just now. Rebuilt. Same result.

Comment: @Pshemo That gives me a white screen. There's nothing there.

Comment: Try: Delete the warned line. Save. Compile. Add it again (somewhere else). Problem still exists? If so, do that with the `getStatus` method.

Comment: @KyleM did the problem go away?

Comment: @acdcjunior I figured it out. See answer if you're interested. Seems like a very specific thing tho..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be due to an Eclipse Indigo bug. The error first appeared when in Eclipse, I switched the default workspace settings to use Java 7 as the compiler. I removed all of the other possible Java compilers, which should force all projects to use Java 7. This can be found under `Project->Properties->Java Compiler`. There is a link that says Configure `Workspace Settings`. All of the individual projects at this point *did* say the "compliance level" was 1.7, which is what I expected. However the error stated above in my answer did not go away until I checked "enable project specific settings" and set it to Java 7. In my opinion this is a bug because if there is only one available compiler that I set as my workspace default compiler, and my project didn't have project specific settings enabled, then clearly it should be using that compiler. However, enabling the project specific settings made my warning message described above go away.